# Javascript WebSQL use one transaction object all the time

Tags: javascript

Hello I have factory which gives functions to work with database, it looks like this:

```
.factory('DBwork', function () {
 var db = openDatabase("...");
 db.transaction(function(tx){
     tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE...");
 });

 var factoryfunctions = {
     insert: function() {
         db.transaction(function(tx){
             tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO...");});
     },
     select: function() {
         db.transaction(function(tx){
             tx.executeSql("SELECT FROM...");});
     }
 };
 return factoryfunctions;
});
```

I need to use one transaction object all the time, or not use transactions at all, is that possible?

Simply, to make it like this.

```
var db = openDatabase("...");
tx = db.transaction();

var factoryfunctions = {
    insert: function() {
        tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO...");
    },
    select: function() {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT FROM...");
    }
};
return factoryfunctions;
```

Im new to javascript so thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to cache *transaction object* for later use. It is unusable after *transaction callback* has completed. In specification's terms it's marked *stale*, so that any other call to its `executeSql()` throws an exception.

There are only three methods available on the *database object*, `transaction()`, `readTransaction()` and `changeVersion()`. There isn't a way to avoid transaction objects.

What you can do however, is call `executeSql()` multiple times in one transaction callback.

See this example, http://html5demos.com/database-rollback.